# Joining two columns on a table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a problem that is quite simple to understand, but for me it is not that simple to implement.

I have a table named **Time**:

```
-----------------------------------
 DAY     TIME1     TIME2
-----------------------------------
 1       08.00     09.40
 1       09.40     10.00
 1       10.00     11.40
 2       08.00     08.50
 2       08.50     10.40
 ----------------------------------
```

What I want to get is like:

```
-------------------
 DAY     TIME     
-------------------
 1       08.00     
 1       09.40     
 1       10.00     
 1       11.00     
 2       08.00     
 2       08.50     
 2       10.40     
 ------------------
```

I have tried this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.val FROM (
  SELECT Time1 AS val FROM Time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Time2 AS val FROM Time
) AS sub
```

And it is only return the Time column. I have no idea about joining the **"Day"** column. While I am trying to add the **"Day"** after the "DISTINCT sub.val", it got error. How to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @All: Thank you for all of your answer. It really helped me a lot to solved the problem with some different ways and resulted the same value. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select distinct day, time1 from mytab
union
select distinct day, time2 from mytab
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.Day, sub.val as Time FROM (
  SELECT Day, Time1 AS val FROM Time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Day, Time2 AS val FROM Time
) AS sub
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    SELECT day, time1 FROM Time
    UNION ALL SELECT day, time2 FROM Time
) AS x
ORDER BY x.day
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
SELECT
    DAY,
    TIME1
FROM
    YourTable AS T
UNION
SELECT
    DAY,
    TIME2
FROM
    YourTable AS T
ORDER BY DAY,TIME1
```